# Error when tried to compile client before connect to server

Tags: c, linux, pointers, casting, client-server

I am trying to connect client to server, so the client can send a message to server.
Here is my code

Server

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int connfd, listenfd, tmp, sin_size;
  struct sockaddr_in servaddr, client;
  char message[100];
  servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  servaddr.sin_port = htons(13);
  bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

  listenfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
  if(listenfd == -1)
  {
    printf("Error create socket\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  tmp = bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&servaddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
  if(tmp == -1)
  {
    printf("Error binding\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  listen(listenfd,2);

  sin_size = sizeof(client);
  connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&client, &sin_size);
  if(connfd == -1)
  {
    printf("Error accept\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  bzero(&message, sizeof(message));
  read(connfd, &message, sizeof(message));
  write(connfd, message, sizeof(message));
  close(connfd);
  close(listenfd);

}
```

Client

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int connfd, listenfd;
  int port = atoi(argv[2]);
  char message[100];

  listenfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
  if(listenfd == -1)
  {
    printf("Error create socket\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  struct sockaddr_in servaddr;

  bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
  servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  servaddr.sin_port = htons(port);
  servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]); 

  connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
  if(connfd == -1)
  {
    printf("Error accept\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  bzero(&message, sizeof(message));
  printf("Input kata: ");
  scanf("%[^\n]",message);
  getchar();
  write(listenfd, &message, sizeof(message));
  read(listenfd, &message, sizeof(message));

  close(listenfd);
}
```

I've compiled and run server (./server 8000) and it's waiting for client to connect.
When I tried to compile there an error on this part

> connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&servaddr,
>   sizeof(servaddr));

which says

```
warning: passing argument 3 of ‘accept’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/socket.h:214:12: note: expected ‘socklen_t * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘long unsigned int’
```

What should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As warning suggets you should pass address of length parameter not actual length.

```
socklen_t szaddr = sizeof(servaddr);
connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&servaddr, &szaddr);
```

Comment: thank you it works. but there's another problem. When I tried to run it ./client (IP) 8000 it said error accept. Why it couldn't accept the IP and port?

Comment: yeah you're right. but it still error to connect althought i've changed the code into   {connfd = connect(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));} Without using binding of course